# Surface integral of a bilinear surface defined by 4 points evenly spaced in 2D

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find an analytical formula to formulate the integral under a bilinear surface defined by 4 points.

The 4 points are evenly spaced in 2D but can have any positive value in their 3rd dimension.

ChatGPT recommended me to use a polynomial fit but it seems that this is an approximation.

My first idea was to take the average of the 4 points and multiply by the surface under the 4 points.
$$Integral=(f(x_0,y_0)+f(x_0+h,y_0)+f(x_0,y_0+h)+f(x_0+h,y_0+h))*h^2/4$$

Is this valid?

If it is not valid, since the points are evenly spaced can I use this or is it a polynomial approximation?
$$f(x, y) = a_{00} + a_{10}x + a_{01}y + a_{11}xy$$

Where:

- $$a_{00} = f(0, 0)$$
- $$a_{10} = f(1, 0) - f(0, 0)$$
- $$a_{01} = f(0, 1) - f(0, 0)$$
- $$a_{11} = f(1, 1) - f(1, 0) - f(0, 1) + f(0, 0)$$

Comment: Please write your formula using MathJax, don't put it as a formula.

Comment: @FabrizzioMuzz, 
Chatgpt: Given the function for bilinear interpolation:

$$
f(x, y) = \frac{1}{(x_2 - x_1)(y_2 - y_1)} \left( f(Q_{11})(x_2 - x)(y_2 - y) + f(Q_{21})(x - x_1)(y_2 - y) + f(Q_{12})(x_2 - x)(y - y_1) + f(Q_{22})(x - x_1)(y - y_1) \right)
$$

with known values at four points \( Q_{11} = (x_1, y_1) \), \( Q_{21} = (x_2, y_1) \), \( Q_{12} = (x_1, y_2) \), and \( Q_{22} = (x_2, y_2) \) and their respective heights \( f(Q_{11}) \), \( f(Q_{21}) \), etc., could you help with the double integration of this function from \( x_1 \) to \( x_2 \) and from \( y_1 \) to \( y_2 \)?

Comment: @FabrizzioMuzz The answer i received from my question:
Certainly! The double integral of the given bilinear interpolation function over the specified region can be calculated as follows:

$$
\int_{y_1}^{y_2} \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(x, y) \, dx \, dy = \frac{(f(Q_{11}) + f(Q_{12}) + f(Q_{21}) + f(Q_{22})) (x_1 - x_2) (y_1 - y_2)}{4}
$$

This result represents the average value of the interpolated surface over the rectangular region defined by the points \( Q_{11}, Q_{21}, Q_{12}, Q_{22} \).

Comment: Because I made a mistake in evaluating the double integral, I deleted my previous comments. ChatGPT is correct, as per https://www.desmos.com/3d/ea4fa6aba7, so the expression for the double integral you provided in the question statement will be correct if you modify it to "work" over a rectangular region instead of a square one.

Comment: If by "evenly spaced" you mean that the points are arranged in a rectangle aligned with the $x$ and $y$ axes, then ChatGPT is correct.